# Fastest way to convert gmpy2 mpz to a bigendian byte-array (bytes)?

Tags: python-3.x, gmpy

I tried several different approaches, from

```
def ToByteArray(x):
    x = int(x)
    return x.to_bytes((x.bit_length() + 7) // 8, byteorder='big')
```

or diving x by 256 and building a new `bytearray` in a loop but it just feels slow compared to the conversion of a normal python int or in gmpy2 c++.

Isn't there something like an `mpz_export` in c++? What is the fastest way to accomplish this?

Edit: The reason I need to convert it to `bytes` is that `hashlib` cannot hash `mpz`. If there is another fast way to get a strong cryptographic (sha256) hash of an `mpz`, without having to convert it to `bytes` first, that might help aswell!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `gmpy2.to_binary()` will do what you need. It converts a `gmpy2` object to portable byte sequence. It uses `mpz_export` to convert the underlying `mpz_t` to a sequence of bytes. A short header containing the `gmpy2` type and the length is placed at the beginning of the byte sequence. For the `gmpy2.mpz` type (and assuming the value is not 0), the header is two bytes long.

```
>>> gmpy2.to_binary(gmpy2.mpz(123456**7))
b'\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe4\x9f\xcc\xfb\xad\xe5\x1f\xec.T'
```